# Netlify deploy has error: WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: gatsby, netlify

When deploying my gatsby site to Netlify I get this error:
WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

// components
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";
import SEO from "../components/seo";

// css

export default function IndexPage() {
// i took out my strip id so I could post online
  const stripe = window.Stripe("stripeID_Here");
  const [sku, setSku] = useState("sku_GKCxZJybZKaHr7");

  const placeOrder = () => {
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [
        {
          sku,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      successUrl: "http://localhost:8000/success",
      cancelUrl: "http://localhost:8000/cancel",
    });
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Home" />


      {/* Popular   */}
      <section id="Popular-items" className="row">
        <div className="container popular-items">
          <h2>Check out our most popular items</h2>
          <article>
            <img src="http://picsum.photos/340/400" alt="SET HAPPENS T-Shirt" />
            <h3>SET HAPPENS T-Shirt</h3>
            <select value={sku} onChange={e => setSku(e.target.value)}>
              <option value="sku_GKCxZJybZKaHr7">Small</option>
              <option value="sku_GK8OJSyke6mMrm">Medium</option>
              <option value="sku_GKCy45LwrpfmV8">Large</option>
            </select>
            <button onClick={placeOrder}>Buy Me</button>
          </article>
        </div>
      </section>
      {/* Popular End */}


    </Layout>
  );
}
```

it says error "window" is not available during server side rendering.

so what can I use in place of window?

Everything else works fine.

Comment: Here's a link to a related page in Gatsby docs => https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/#how-to-check-if-window-is-defined

Answer (score 2):

During development react component are only run in the browser where `window` is defined so it works properly. But when `building` react components are rendered on the server where `window` is not defined. That is the reason you are seeing this error.

You can fix this error by calling the `window` in `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` hook.

You can also try doing this

```js
const stripe = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.Stripe("stripeID_Here");
```